# JavaScript: How to remove last word from a string only if the word contains an integer 0-9?

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement

So I'm aware that I can remove the last word from a string of words by using lastIndexOf(" "), but I'd like to add the condition that the word should only be removed if it contains an integer 0-9.

I'm asking because I'd like to separate company names from their reference tags (if such tags exist) for a list of data. These reference tags are guaranteed to contain at least one integer 0-9. For example, I have the string "Cisco Systems RX4510", and I'd like to remove the "RX4510" to just get the company name, "Cisco Systems." However, for another string "Electronic Arts", which has no reference tag, I just leave it alone.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression which, after the last space, looks ahead for a digit character, and then matches word characters until the end of the string, `$`:

```js
const str1 = 'Cisco Systems RX4510';
const str2 = 'Electronic Arts';
const re = / (?=.*\d)\w+$/;
console.log(str1.replace(re, ''));
console.log(str2.replace(re, ''));
```

Note that this will replace the space before the last word too. If you want to preserve the last space, use a word boundary instead:

```
/\b(?=.*\d)\w+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last character with `s.charAt(s.length)` (there are cleaner ways but this one supports really old browsers) and then check if it's a number with `parseInt` and `isNaN`. Example:

```
if (!isNaN(parseInt(s.charAt(s.length), 10))) {
    // do something
}
```